# The stock hardware question is a good one

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[What is the difference between a stock-hardware and a micro-coded machine in "A Critique of Common Lisp"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193696/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stock-hardware-and-a-micro-coded-machine) started out ranty, and people got carried away in the comments, but the underlying question is a good one.  It's interesting, it's relevant, and deserves an answer.  Could someone please clean up the comments and give it another shot?  I have an unambiguous and clear answer ready to go.

I understand rants make people not want to help.  That's what the edit button is for, not the close button.

Comment: Pro-tip:  Don't start your questions with a rant in the first place, and you'll get much better results.

Comment: As an aside, comments cleaned up. If I missed anything, flag.

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4545/how-should-i-handle-ranting-in-answers

Answer (score 4):

OK. With three reopen votes I've added mine to reopen the question.

Let's see how it fares in it's current incarnation.

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem the question is asking about?

I have no issue with gaining general knowledge of programming history (and if it is a history question, please remember to tag it as such - the answer for 1984 is different than the answer three decades later).  It should be answered in that context if it is a history question. "Vaxes, MC68000’s, or any truly ‘stock’ hardware." as opposed to that of a [lisp machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine).  Likely the best answer to the current incarnation is explaining how the lisp machine was made and how that differs from everything else.  I don't know if anyone is going to try to make a hardware lisp machine today (or ever again).

If there is another question that is hiding behind this one - for example asking about the critique of LISP and if it is still a valid critique in today's computing world is one that is likely more relevant and much more interesting to the people reading and answering it.